# Get whole word that starts with specific string

Tags: c#, regex

Input string:

> if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id =
> object_id(N'[dbo].[dbo.uspSomeCondition]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id,
> N'IsProcedure') = 1)

Expected output:

dbo.sysobjects
dbo.uspSomeCondition

Tried Regex like so in C# with no luck:

```
String regex = "\\dbo.\\b"
```

How to specify something on the lines of dbo.* word boundary that ends with a space?

Comment: Please provide [mre]. Input and Desired output are missing.   Also the tag for the database (MSSQL?) is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pattern `dbo\.[^\s\]]*`

Explanation:

`dbo\.` - match `dbo.` literally

`[^\s\]]*` - match one or more characters other than `\s` (whitespace) and `]`

Generally idea is: match your anchor string, which is `dbo.` and then match until unwanted characters, in this case whitespace or closing square bracket, and put all these characters inside negated character class.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gi7Mbc/2)

C# code:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[dbo.uspSomeCondition]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)", @"dbo\.[^\s\]]*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

`dbo\.\S+\b`

Match `dbo.` literally, and then match one or more non whitespace characters until the word boundary is encountered.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D0wpGd/2/)